# When I write "dir" I get this error TypeError: descriptor 'encode' requires a 'str' and the reason is "if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sockets

```
from __future__ import print_function
import socket
import sys

def socket_create():

    try:

        global host
        global port
        global s
        host = ''
        port = 9999
        s = socket.socket()
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Socket creation error: " + str(msg))



def socket_bind():

    try:
        global host
        global port
        global  s
        print("Binding socket to port: " + str(port))
        s.bind((host,port))
        s.listen(5)
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Socket binding error: " + str(msg) + "\n" + "Retrying...")
        socket_bind()


def socket_accept():

    conn, address = s.accept()
    print("Connection has been established | " + "IP " + address[0] + "| Port " + str(address[1]))
    send_commands(conn)
    conn.close()


def send_commands(conn):

    while True:
        cmd = input()
        if cmd == 'quit':
            conn.close()
            s.close()
            sys.exit()
        if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0:
            conn.send(str.encode(cmd))
            client_response = str(conn.recv(1024), "utf-8")
            print(client_response, end ="")

def main():

    socket_create()
    socket_bind()
    socket_accept()

main()
```

Comment: I also have a client.py file if required please let me know!

Comment: You should post the full error!! Posting the client wont do any harm as long as it's reasonably small.

Comment: You should make your mind up about which version of python you are using. Are you aiming for something that is 2/3 cross compatible? String handling particularly around encoding/decoding is notably different and hoping to get something to work across both versions might take some extra work.

Comment: Please do not abuse tags: there is nothing about `subprocess` here nor `python-3.x` (since you import `print_function`) and while your code is using sockets, your issue is not related at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `raw_input` not `input` (*cf.* https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html). Have a look at the value and the type of what is returned to you by `input`.

Also `str` takes only one argument (few lines down, in your `if`).

Comment: Thank you sir,I will let you know if i get any more errors.

Comment: Now I get this error "TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)..I know you mentioned above that str can only take one argument but could you please tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe you could read the documentation on [str](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) and [str class methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)